# Hide Web Template?

Tags: web-template

I cant figure out how to hide a web template in the user interface, is this even possible?

I found this answear to my question at [Mirjam's blog](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/0001/01/01/using-web-templates-to-create-site-collections.aspx), but I can't find the "Page layouts and site templates" under Look and Feel, so it didn't really help me.

> Blockquote There is not "hidden" property for the WebTemplate element, like there is in the webtemp.xml files, but you can use the SharePoint user interface to hide web templates from it. You can do this by going into Site Settings and browsing to Page layouts and site templates under Look and Feel. In here you can select templates that can be used to create sub sites. Be aware that using this feature means you will have to enable new templates that can be used manually.

Mirjam

Answer (score 5):

The "page layouts and site templates" page that is referred to in the post link you provided applies only to SharePoint "publishing" sites. These are sites that have the publishing features activated at the site collection and site level.

If your site is not in fact a publishing site, or if you wish to hide templates from within central admin, the only way to hide templates is to edit the webtemp.xml files. It's doable, but not a supported thing to do.

[EDIT]

So after doing some research, it seems that WebTemplates can be farm or site collection scoped.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx

Based on that information, if you create your web template and package it into a site-scoped feature, the web template should only be available to create subsites if that feature has been activated.

Comment: But "webtemp.xml" isn't part of Web Template, only Site Template or Site Definition if I remember correct?

Comment: Ah I see. So you are talking about a site that you've saved as a template?

Comment: I'm talking about a Web Template. It has an element.xml file containing a WebTemplate element and a ONet.xml, nothing more or less.